# Mysql Join without duplicates(theory)?

Tags: php, mysql, azure, pdo

Okay, before I start it's good to mention that I have read (and tryed) countless topics here on stackoverflow and on the internet, but there seems to be no straight foward answer for this simple question.

So here goes the situation:

**table1** (id, name)

1,name1

2,name2

3,name3

**table2** (id, id_table1, field_name)

1,1,field1

2,1,field2

What I want to do is just to display the first table id and it's field "name" when there's any record that matches id_table1 in the second table. I tryed join, group, inner join, left join, but nothing seems to solve my problem....

Expected output:

id: 1 - name: name1

Last code tryed:

SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id_table1 GROUP BY table1.id

Comment: I'm not quite getting this. Could you post sample output as well?

Comment: Would help if you posted what you tried with sample output and let us know why it wasn't what you where looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do away with your problem.

```
select table1.id, table1.name from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id_table1
group by table1.id
```

Comment: If duplication is your issue, use `DISTINCT`: `SELECT DISTINCT table1.id, table1.name FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id_table1`

Comment: added to group the results. should not longer give you duplicates

Answer (score 0):

What about
    select t.* from table1 t where t.id in (select id_table1 from table2)

?